# I can't view the uploaded files in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have built an application using laravel that uploads pdf files to the `public/pdfs/books/` folder. Then I am trying to create a pop up window that will display the uploaded file using the url.Bit while trying to view the file using my pop up box I am getting the following error.

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/laragon/www/Uploader/public/pdfs/books/book.pdf

Can anyone suggest why I am getting this error? I even tried to load the file from another directory outside the application and got the same error. How Can I view the file from my application uploaded to folder

Comment: Sounds like a permission issue...

Comment: How can I set permission in laravel

Comment: I mean folder's permission. Check if Apache's user (if you're using Apache) has access to the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the folder url like this. Because your application is running in local server So it should be able to view the file that starts with `http`.
To make the link for view use the following code in blade:

```
{{URL:to('/').'pdfs/abstracts/fillename.pdf'}}
```

Or use similar type of mechanism so the file is loaded with `http` protocol instead of from local directory starting with `file:///C:`

Answer (score 1):

Can you view the file from browser?
file:///C:/laragon/www/Uploader/public/pdfs/books/book.pdf

If not, you should recheck your upload code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like permission issue, try `chmod 775 -R *` command in your `/Uploader/public/pdfs` directory. You could also try changing file permission in cpanel